# Adding separators between menu items

Tags: key-bindings, menus

Have made the following KMAP keymap, and would like to add separators in the menu.  To separate the `Hide` keymap from the `Show` keymap.  How can I do it?

```
(defvar tika-outlmenu-kmap
  (let ((kmap (make-sparse-keymap)))

    (define-key kmap [hide]
                (cons "Hide" (make-sparse-keymap "Hide")))

    (define-key kmap [hide outl-hide-body]
                '(menu-item "Hide Body" outline-hide-body
                            :help "Hide bodies, visible headings"))

    (define-key kmap [show]
                (cons "Show" (make-sparse-keymap "Show")))

    (define-key kmap [show outl-show-entry]
                '(menu-item "Show Entry" outline-show-entry
                            :help "Show body"))

    (define-key kmap [show outl-show-all]
                '(menu-item "Show All" outline-show-all
                            :help "Show all"))

    kmap))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emacs is self–documenting. It’s got a built–in manual, and the manual has a whole chapter dedicated to adding separators to menus; see [Chapter 23.18.1.3 Menu Separators](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Menu-Separators.html).

Basically all you do is add `(menu-item "---")` to your keymap wherever you want a separator.

There are also some additional options, such as `(menu-item "--space")` if you want a gap instead of a gap with a line in it. There are about a dozen or so possibilities, if you care about them. Check the manual for details.